# .htaccess: Rewrite entire URL if specific directory is called

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm 90% there but I'm missing something obvious. I am doing local web development of a site. The media directory of the site I'm working on is huge - upwards of 15 GB. Instead of copying that and having to update it periodically just for the sake of viewing this images in my local environment, I want to redirect any requests into the media/ directory back to the production site.

From this...

```
localhost:8888/sitefolder/media/*
```

To this...

```
www.productionserver.com/media/*
```

This is what I have so far but I think I need to use the Rewrite Condition directive:

```
RewriteRule ^media/(.*)$ http://www.productionserver.com/media/$1[QSA,R=301,L]
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some syntax issues, you need a space after `$1` and QSA isn't needed:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^media/(.*)$ http://www.productionserver.com/media/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

- Make sure this is placed in `sitefolder/.htaccess`
- Make sure this is first rule after `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: For whatever reason it's not working. I'm going to keep trying with a few variations. I've been restarting MAMP everytime after modifying .htaccess. The images are publicly available and I can navigate to them in a browser but the redirect won't kick in.

Comment: No need to start MAMP. Can you tell me location of your `.htaccess` and if there is any other code as well?

Comment: You had it right. I'll suffice it to say that the web application I'm using has an interesting file structure. Thank you!