# Redirect all requests to include context prefix

Tags: php, apache

I have a webspace which looks like `www.mydomain.com/~myusername/` and at the moment if I create a link something like :

```
<a href="/">home</a>
```

this resolves to

```
www.mydomain.com/
```

How can I redirect this to go to my own root, i.e. `www.mydomain.com/~myusername/`

Comment: Have you got time to test ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19690041/htaccess-rewrite-entire-url-if-specific-directory-is-called), try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~myusername/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

But I think you must set up a virtual host !

Hope this helps,

Comment: Have you got time to test ?